# Firebase & Ionic: Blocked a frame with origin "https://project-xxx.firebaseapp.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to Firebase and I'm trying to implement Firebase in my Ionic apps.

I have follow the step to initialize the firebase by paste the following code in my index.html

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "project-xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-xxx.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var database = firebase.database().ref();

</script>
```

When I try to run the apps via `ionic serve', it gave me the following error in log.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://project-xxx.firebaseapp.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Can someone advice me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? @fahmishah

Comment: Yeah i get the same error

Comment: It's been a year and currently I develop apps using Ionic 2 and there is no issue at all with Firebase.